# Expressions of volume and surface area

Tags: volume, area

Now I understand that the volume of a cuboid is **V = whd** but what I am struggling with is the following:

If **w** and **d** are both equal lets call them **x**, then how can I find an expression for **h** in terms of **x**? The closest I can get is

**h = V / x^2**

Is this correct?

In continuation how would I go about finding the surface area **A** in terms of **x** only using the answer from the first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

The surface area of a cuboid with dimensions $w,h,d$ is $$A=2(wh+wd+hd)$$

This can be seen by computing the area of each of the faces of the cuboid and the adding them.

**EDIT:**

In your example, this reduces to $$A=2(xh+x^2+hx)=2x^2+4xh$$
Now, the question asks that you express this in terms of $x$ (not in terms of $x$ *only*) using the equation from the first question, i.e. $h=\frac{V}{x^2}$. So we substitute this expression for $h$ into the equation for the area to get $$A=2x^2+4x\frac{V}{x^2}=2x^2+4\frac{V}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Though I know the formula for the surface area the part that confuses me in the question is writing A in terms of x only. So if A = 2(xh + x^2 + hx) how is it possible to show A with only x? Perhaps I am not understanding the question.

Comment: That is not what the question asks: You can express $A$ using both $x$ and $V$.

Comment: So when a question asks in terms of x only as in this example, I am still able to use other values along with x? For example A = 2x + h etc?

Comment: @Anon Not quite. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: I see now thank you for the clarification

Comment: No problem! :) Since you're new to the site (and since I have no shame in life :P) I wanted to let you know that if you like an answer, you can upvote and/or "accept" it (the latter is done by pressing the tick below the up/down-vote arrows next to the answer) and make the answerer very happy. Note that you can only accept one answer per question you ask, but you can upvote as many answers as you want. Cheers!

Comment: Not a problem I've done that, thanks again!